# Symfony How to Determine whether user was authenticated using rememberme token

Tags: symfony, remember-me

I have implemented remember me functionality in Symfony 3. Basically "Remember Me" should be enabled only for specific user roles.

Now an User with Role called "Admin" has selected "Remember Me" and logged into the application, an record is created in "rememberme_token" table. The same user has bookmarked the landing URL and closed the browser.

When the same user reloads the bookmarked URL, the application is allowing the user with "Admin" role to access the application but I want to restrict this. Users with "User" role should only be allowed to access the application when they are coming back to site using the bookmarked URL.

Basically I want to intercept the request and determine whether the user is authenticated using "Remember Me" cookie or not?

Comment: Symfony differenciates remembered users from logged in users via the IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY/IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED roles. But we would need to know more about your custom authentication

Comment: I am using guard authentication and access_control.
access_control:
- {path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN}
- {path: ^/hotels, roles: ROLE_HOTEL}

Comment: Here is the complete info
I am using guard authentication and access_control.
access_control:
- {path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN}
- {path: ^/hotels, roles: ROLE_HOTEL}
- {path: ^/browse, roles: ROLE_USER}
- {path: ^/user, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_HOTEL, ROLE_USER] }

Comment: I am not understanding the question. Is Admin allowed to access the landing page? If you don't want Admin user coming back to the site with authentication remembered, why are you having 'Remember Me' functionality for admin user?

Comment: Good Question. We currently have only one login control for all the users So, Admin and all other users will use the same login screen. Only after authenticating the credentials we get to know the user role and frankly I am not able to restrict the triggering of "Remember Me" for users other than "ROLE_USER". Though we notify to all the website users that "Remember Me" is enabled only for users but in the background "Remember Me" functionality kicks in and cookie is created for all the users. I thought of restricting the user when they come back to the application using "Remember Me" cookie.